# How to use sessions in a webtask?

Tags: webtask

There's no persistent memory in webtasks, so `passport`'s default [MemoryStore](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionoptions) won't work. I do know webtask offers [persistant storage](https://webtask.io/docs/editor/storage) so perhaps I could use that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Although it would be possible to use `context.storage` by hacking with a compiler (e.g. a fork of [webtask-tools](https://github.com/auth0/webtask-tools)) it's probably not worth it as storage size limit is 500kb.

I would just get a free 500mb mongodb database from [mlab](https://mlab.com/plans/pricing/) and use [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo).